# Dotnet Maui: Can't bind a BindableProperty. What would be the solution?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, maui

Here is the main page, classic.

## MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:SuperLabelApp.Resources.Views"
             x:Class="SuperLabelApp.MainPage">

    <view:SuperLabel Text="Hello, World"/>

</ContentPage>
```

## MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace SuperLabelApp;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

SuperLabel has a bindable property for Text that I want him to pass to SuperLabelChild so its label is updated with the value from main page.

## SuperLabel.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:SuperLabelApp.Resources.Views"
             x:Class="SuperLabelApp.Resources.Views.SuperLabel">
    <view:SuperLabelChild Text="{Binding Text}" />
</ContentView>
```

## SuperLabel.xaml.cs

```
namespace SuperLabelApp.Resources.Views;

public partial class SuperLabel : ContentView
{
    #region [Constructor]

    public SuperLabel()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Bindable Properties]

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Text),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(SuperLabel),
        default(string),
        propertyChanged: onchanged
        );

    #endregion

    #region [Properties]

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    static void onchanged(BindableObject obj, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Debug Super Label");
    }

}
```

## SuperLabelChild.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SuperLabelApp.Resources.Views.SuperLabelChild">
    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
</ContentView>
```

## SuperLabelChild.xaml.cs

```
namespace SuperLabelApp.Resources.Views;

public partial class SuperLabelChild : ContentView
{
    #region [Constructor]

    public SuperLabelChild()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    #endregion

    #region [Bindable Properties]

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Text),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(SuperLabelChild),
        default(string),
        propertyChanged: onchanged
        );

    #endregion

    #region [Properties]

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    static void onchanged(BindableObject obj, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Debug Super Label Child");
    }

}
```

The value from MainPage never reaches SuperLabelChild. the onchanged event from SuperLabel is triggered when I change "Hello, World", but not the one in SuperLabelChild.
If I change the binding of SuperLabel.xaml for a text like "Hi", I reach the onchanged event, and the Label in the UI changes for "Hi".

I understand I am probably doing something wrong, but why does it work with the binding of:

`SuperLabel->SuperLabelChild->Label,`

but not for

`MainPage->SuperLabel->SuperLabelChild`

Am I missing something?

Note that the example is simple, and is just a replication of a real problem I have.

I tried Changing the bindings, changing the order.
Making the BindableProperty TwoWays.

I'm expecting the binding of SuperLabel to notify its changes to the one of SuperLabelChild but it doesn't.

I understand I could just use c# to change the value of the label, but I want to understand how bindings work, and it's hard to debug.

Comment: Binding is typically downstream in that, you declare your Bindings in your MainPage.xaml. Here, however, the Bindings are declared in your downstream components, but, the issue you're having is your MainPage.xaml is rewriting the toplevel Binding replacing it with static string "Hello, World". So, you're Binding is fragile because it was easily overriden.

Answer (score 2):

Make some changes and it will work.

For **SuperLabel.xaml**,

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         x:Name="superLabel">

        <view:SuperLabelChild Text="{Binding Text,Source={x:Reference superLabel}}" />

</ContentView>
```

For **SuperLabelChild.xaml**,

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         x:Name="superLabelChild">

    <Label Text="{Binding Text,Source={x:Reference superLabelChild}}" />
</ContentView>
```

Also, you don't have to set `this.BindingContext=this` in these two files.

For more info, you could refer to [.NET MAUI ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview#define-the-ui).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-7.0) and then pass parameters with `TemplateBinding` which binds a property of an element that is in a `ControlTemplate` to a public property that is defined by the templated custom control or templated page.

So change your **SuperLabelChild.xaml** like below:

```
<ContentView.ControlTemplate> 
       <ControlTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                  <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
            <ContentPresenter/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
       </ControlTemplate>
</ContentView.ControlTemplate>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Pass parameters with TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-parameters-with-templatebinding).